# Grouping a value according to each criteria

Tags: sql, db2

I have three tables like Sip,SipLine and Hareket and i want to join these tables and get some results. As you see below, what i want to get is total quantities of No according to each Kalite. With the what i did, i get the multiple rows but i don't want to this.

My query is:

```
>select 
Sip.No,
Sip.DetNo,
CASE WHEN H.Kal = '1' THEN
SUM(H.Miktar) 
ELSE
null END as Kalite1,
CASE WHEN H.Kal = '2' THEN
SUM(H.Miktar) 
ELSE
null END as Kalite2,
CASE WHEN H.Kal = '3' THEN
SUM(H.Miktar) 
ELSE
null END as Kalite3,
CASE WHEN H.Kal = '4' THEN
SUM(H.Miktar) 
ELSE
null END as Kalite4,
CASE WHEN H.Kal = '5' THEN
SUM(H.Miktar) 
ELSE
null END as Kalite5


>from Sip





>left join SipSatir SipL on
Sip.Srkt = SipL.SipSatirSrkt and
Sip.Say = SipL.SipSatirSay and
Sip.No = SipL.SipSatirNo


>left join Hareket H on
H.Srkt = SipL.SALESipRDERSrkt and 
H.DetNo = SipL.DetNo and
H.MNo = SipL.MKNo and
H.DKODNo01 = SipL.KODNo01 and
H.DKODNo02 = SipL.KODNo02 and
H.DKODNo03 = SipL.KODNo03 and
H.DKODNo04 = SipL.KODNo04 and
H.DKODNo05 = SipL.KODNo05 and
H.DKODNo06 = SipL.KODNo06 and
H.DKODNo07 = SipL.KODNo07 and
H.DKODNo08 = SipL.KODNo08 and
H.DKODNo09 = SipL.KODNo09 and
H.DKODNo10 = SipL.KODNo10


>where H.TEMPLATENo = '102' and H.MNo in ('50','60') and H.DetNo <> ''

>group by
Sip.No,
Sip.DetNo,
H.Kal
```

The Output:

| No | DetNo | KALITE1 | KALITE2 | KALITE3 | KALITE4 | KALITE5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202001322-2 | 202001322-2 | 733.74 | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| 202001322-2 | 202001322-2 | -------------- | 314.22 | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| 202001322-2 | 202001322-2 | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- | 19.32 |
| 202001933 | 202001933 | 199.65 | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| 202002366-1 | 202002366 | 147.7 | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| 202002366-1 | 202002366 | -------------- | 26.81 | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |

I want to get the result below:

| No | DetNo | KALITE1 | KALITE2 | KALITE3 | KALITE4 | KALITE5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202001322-2 | 202001322-2 | 733.74 | 314.22 | -------------- | -------------- | 19.32 |
| 202001933 | 202001933 | 199.65 | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| 202002366-1 | 202002366 | 147.7 | 26.81 | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |

How can i get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the `CASE` inside the aggregate functions (It is called conditional aggregation) and don't use `kal` in `group by` as follows:

```
>select 
Sip.No,
Sip.DetNo,
SUM(CASE WHEN H.Kal = '1' THEN H.Miktar END) as Kalite1,
SUM(CASE WHEN H.Kal = '2' THEN H.Miktar END) as Kalite2,
SUM(CASE WHEN H.Kal = '3' THEN H.Miktar END) as Kalite3,
SUM(CASE WHEN H.Kal = '4' THEN H.Miktar END) as Kalite4,
SUM(CASE WHEN H.Kal = '5' THEN H.Miktar END) as Kalite5
>from Sip
>left join SipSatir SipL on
Sip.Srkt = SipL.SipSatirSrkt and
Sip.Say = SipL.SipSatirSay and
Sip.No = SipL.SipSatirNo
>left join Hareket H on
H.Srkt = SipL.SALESipRDERSrkt and 
H.DetNo = SipL.DetNo and
H.MNo = SipL.MKNo and
H.DKODNo01 = SipL.KODNo01 and
H.DKODNo02 = SipL.KODNo02 and
H.DKODNo03 = SipL.KODNo03 and
H.DKODNo04 = SipL.KODNo04 and
H.DKODNo05 = SipL.KODNo05 and
H.DKODNo06 = SipL.KODNo06 and
H.DKODNo07 = SipL.KODNo07 and
H.DKODNo08 = SipL.KODNo08 and
H.DKODNo09 = SipL.KODNo09 and
H.DKODNo10 = SipL.KODNo10
>where H.TEMPLATENo = '102' and H.MNo in ('50','60') and H.DetNo <> ''
>group by
Sip.No,
Sip.DetNo
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT No, DetNo, SUM(KALITE1), SUM(KALITE2), SUM(KALITE3), SUM(KALITE4), SUM(KALITE5)
FROM
( *your existing query* )
GROUP BY No, DetNo